# web app file spec mismatch between Eclipse project and Eclipse-generated .war

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am developing a web app in Eclipse for deployment to a Tomcat server. Currenly, it works fine when I launch it from within Eclipse, using a Tomcat installation on the localhost. But when I export a .war file and install it on a remote server, it fails because of a mismatch between the file system in Eclipse and the file system in the .war file.

When Eclipse created the Java EE project for me, it created the following directory structure:

```
app
    src
    WebContent
```

I put all of my Java source files---servlets and classes---in the src directory, and all of the Web files---.jsp, .html, and various .xml resources---in WebContent.

So that my app could use the .xml resources, I put them all in a WebContent subdirectory named, not coincidentally, resources.

I then defined a variable pointing to these files...

```
path_to_resources = "WebContent" + pathMrkr + "resources" + pathMrkr;
// where pathMrkr = System.getProperty("file.separator")
```

...in each class that needs to access the .xml files.

This works well when I run the app from within Eclipse.  But when I export and deploy the app if fails. The .war file Eclipse creates does not include a WebContent folder, so the search for resources fails, and the app crashes, shutting down Tomcat in the process.

So, I guess I'm looking for some advice on how best to structure Eclipse or my app so that a single code base works both in Eclipse on the localhost and from a .war file on a remote server, with a minimum of fuss and fidgeting with build configurations or having to manually edit the .war file.

While I don't think it's pertinent, for the record my system is:

Eclipse Luna, on a Windows 10 localhost, with Tomcat 8 and Java 8. The remote server running in the cloud is a CentOS 5.5 system running Tomcat 7 and Java 8.

Thanks.

Jerry